Why does this MOSFET amplify more and more the longer it runs?
I built a simple power amplifier using a IRF510 MOSFET in a common source configuration: The incoming signal is connected to the gate, source goes directly to ground, and the drain has a 100 uH inductor connecting it to Vdd.  Output is from the drain via a 100 nF capacitor.
The amplifier amplifies a 7 MHz signal quite well (with huge distortion, but that's acceptable in this application.)

When you power up the amp, the peak to peak signal may be 14 V.  As you let it run, the peak to peak signal grows.  If you e.g. wait for it to be 15 V, power down, and then power back up, the amplification might be 14.8 V - and then it continues to grow.
I've also noticed that when I power it on, the peak to peak amplitude varies - one day it may be 14 V, another day 15 V.
Why does it do this? My best guess is thermal.  Perhaps the MOSFET's properties change in a way that makes it work "better" (for my application) as it gets warmer.  And perhaps different days (or times of day) have different ambient room temperature, for initial amplification.
Are there other potential explanations?
Whether or not that's the correct cause, it leaves me with two issues:

Is there a way I can artificially "warm it up" to get the greater amplification? The nature of the application (a CW transmitter) is that sometimes the amp will be on, sometimes off.  Is there a simple way I can keep it warm (or whatever else is needed for high amplification)?
How can I measure alternate designs? I've experimented with alternate designs (e.g. making L3 100 uH instead of 10 uH, as originally designed).  But given the large variation over time, it's hard to measure the results, or know how much a change helps.


Update
Hypothesis: The MOSFET's amplification is not changing.  Rather, R_load, which is a resistor used as a dummy load, gets hot and increases its resistance.  As the load resistor gets hotter, its resistance goes up, and so the voltage drop across it lessens, giving a higher peak to peak voltage, and greater voltage amplification (though not greater power amplification).
I intend to test this by artificially changing the temperature of the load resistor and measuring.
Does this hypothesis explain the observations?
Re Comments: I don't see any other aspect of the system changing over time.  The waveforms (at all the points along the circuit I've measured) have the same shape on the oscilloscope, and, frequency stable within < 1 kHZ.

Please show complete circuit schematic as built (not a woefully cropped excerpt) and photos of layout.

@TimWilliams Do you mean a photo of the actual physical circuit? Will do, and update the schematic with any as-built deviations, once I get access (not currently colocated).  In the meantime, I posted the schematic as designed (which still has L3 = 10 uH, not 100 uH).

@TimWilliams In software, the goal when reproducing a problem is to reduce it to a minimal example that shows the problem.  Is something similar helpful in EE, or is more better? For example, the behavior occurs with the circuit as designed, which uses an IRF4905L for controlling Vtx, but it also occurs when I remove the IRF4905L and simply connect Vtx directly to Vcc.  Which of those is most useful here: the full circuit as conceived, or a simpler circuit which manifests the problem?

Does any other feature of output waveform change, not just peak-to-peak amplitude?  Eg: does the frequency change?  Does the output waveform change shape?

Especially the IRF510 lacks, because of the simple and direct DC coupling between the different stages, a stable bias point.  Drain current and gain will therefore be dependable on supply voltage and well-being (temperature) of the driver/predriver/final transistors. In addition, the PMOS in the high side switch is upside-down and can only switch between Vcc and Vcc minus a diode voltage drop.

Scope varies. For high-frequency problems like this, I would air on the side of completeness. EMC problems in particular can have total-system scope, where the mere fitness of panels, routing of cables, can determine pass or fail of radio emissions: without knowing which panel, cable, PCB, etc. is suspect, we have to see everything. Here, the driver (Q3) might be weak; what are the waveforms and amplitudes on it? Does it vary with voltage? Temperature?

@FabioBarone Raonoke TimWilliams Updated

What temperature does Q4 case get to, too hot to touch, or just warm?  Ditto for the dummy load. What voltage are you measuring, the one across the load, or the drain of Q4, or something else?

@FabioBarone Neither is too hot to touch, or very noticeably warm.  I'm measuring the voltage across the load.

@SRobertJames  Noted.  Interesting that the load resistor temperature is not increasing much.  How are you making the measurement?  Using a scope, then with your eyeball or the scopes measurement features?

@FabioBarone The scope measures peak-to-peak voltage.  It's very similar behavior, done on different days.

An easy way to test your hypothesis: apply some warmed air to various components & observe the response.  A heat gun or hairdryer would make a suitable source of warm air.  You could also apply cold air, via a can of refrigerant  available from any decent electronic service supply shop.

Seems ok for an amplifier at 7 MHz ...
Made with microcap v12
Power gain = ~ 130 with some 10 mW input ... Efficiency = ~ 70 %.
And changing the value of the self from 10 uH to 100 uH does not really change anything.


On LTspice, changing the value from 10 uH to 100 uH didn't change anything.  But in the physical built circuit, it does! LTspice overpredicts the gain considerably either way, but 100 uH works best.  Do you have any ideas as to why the power gain might grow over time?

@SRobertJames What inductors are you using? Inductors especially, are not all created equally.

The inductor model in this simulation is not complete ... Parasitic capacitor can do best.

The amplifier is "not well" stabilized with "gain" and DC ... All make vary the power at output.
